# Celery, RabbitMQ messages keep getting sent

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

Here is the setup - django project with celery and a CloudAMQP rabbitMQ worker doing the message brokering.

My Celery/RabbitMQ settings:

```
# RabbitMQ & Celery settings
BROKER_URL = 'ampq://guest:guest@localhost:5672/' # Understandably fake
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30
BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 30
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

A docker container running celery with the following command:

```
bash -c 'cd django && celery -A pkm_main worker -E -l info --concurrency=3'
```

The shared_task definition:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def push_notification(user_id, message):
    logging.critical('Push notifications sent')
    return {'status': 'success'}
```

And me actually calling it when something happens (I have omitted some of the code because it does not seem to be relevant):

```
from notificatons.tasks import push_notification

    def like_this(self, **args):
    # Do like stuff and then do .delay()
    push_notification.delay(media.user.id, request.user.username + ' has liked your item')
```

So when this is ran - everything seems fine and dandy - the output looks like so:

```
worker_1 | [2016-03-25 09:03:34,888: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: notifications.tasks.push_notification[8443bd88-fa02-4ea4-9bff-8fbec8c91516]
worker_1 | [2016-03-25 09:03:35,333: CRITICAL/Worker-1] Push notifications sent
worker_1 | [2016-03-25 09:03:35,336: INFO/MainProcess] Task notifications.tasks.push_notification[8443bd88-fa02-4ea4-9bff-8fbec8c91516] succeeded in 0.444933412999s: {'status': 'success'}
```

So from what I gather the task has been ran and executed properly, the messages should be stopped and RabbitMQ should stop.

But in my RabbitMQ Management I see messages getting published and delivered non-stop:

[image: RabbitMQ Admin GUI]

So what I'm gathering from this is that RabbitMQ is trying to send some sort of confirmation and failing and retrying? Is there a way to actually turn this behavior off?

All help and advice is warmly welcomed.

EDIT: Forgot to mentions something important - until I call on push_notification.delay() the message tab is empty save for the heartbeat that comes and goes every 30 seconds. Only after I have called .delay() does this happen.

EDIT 2: CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE settings (I've tried running with and without them - there was no difference but adding them just in case)

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "minutely_process_all_notifications": {
        'task': 'transmissions.tasks.process_all_notifications',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*')
    }
}
```

EDIT 3: Added View code. Also I'm not using the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE. I'm just keeping the config in the code for future scheduled tasks

```
from notifications.tasks import push_notification

class MediaLikesView(BaseView):
    def post(self, request, media_id):
        media = self.get_object(media_id)
        data = {}
        data['media'] = media.id
        data['user'] = request.user.id
        serializer = MediaLikeSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            like = serializer.save()
            push_notification.delay(media.user.id, request.user.username + ' has liked your item')
            serializer = MediaGetLikeSerializer(like)
            return self.get_mocked_pagination_response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return self.get_mocked_pagination_response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Could you please post the code where you call the method `like_this`? and the value you have for `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` if any?

Comment: Hey. I've added the schedule. The method itself is inside a post method in a Django Rest Framework view class. Not sure if that would be helpful but I can toss it in there too.

Comment: Where is the method `process_all_notifications`? I mean, it should be at `transmissions.tasks` but, i don't see this code, could you please added it as well?

Comment: Please add the code of the view as well

Comment: There is no such method. It's just placeholder settings for the future if I ever want to add a CELERYBEAT and do crons.

Comment: if you call `push_notification` directly in the view, why you have a method `like_this`, where do you call this last method? It is important you edit the question and post the code *as is* otherwise will be hard to find the issue

Comment: I don't think you need to set 
```
BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30
BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 30
```
using the default values instead, try to remove these settings and check again.

Comment: I just omitted some of the irrelevant code. I'm almost sure the issue is coming from Celery settings since the job (shown by the logs) is actually completed.

Comment: Remove these settings BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30 BROKER_HEARTBEAT = 30 and try again

Comment: That didn't seem to help. There was an answer earlier suggesting something similar. If I don't actually trigger push_notification.delay() ever I can only see the heartbeat every 30 seconds which is okay.

But once I trigger push_notification.delay() rabbitMQ seems to be trying it's best to send some message and fails but I have no clue how to debug this or find our what is happening in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Celery's mingle and gossiping. Disable by adding `--without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat` to the command line arguments.

Also don't forget to set `BROKER_HEARTBEAT = None` when you've disabled heartbeats on the commandline, otherwise you'll disconnected after 30s. It's most often better to rely on TCP keepalive then AMQP heartbeats, or even worse, Celery's own heartbeats.

Comment: Carl, may whatever diety you happen to believe in bless you and your entire family. That did the trick. Thank you so very much. I'm going to go read-up on what gossip and mingle does.